# What is the 'context' that is being passed into the onUpdate, onEnabled, onDeleted, and onDisabled methods of the AppWidgetProvider?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-context

Is it the ApplicationContext or the ActivityContext of my app?  Does it make a difference which one it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it the ApplicationContext or the ActivityContext of my app?

You should not care. It is a `Context`, period. Any assumptions you make beyond that are undocumented and subject to change.

That being said, since there is not necessarily an `Activity` in your entire application, the `Context` is rather unlikely to be an `Activity`.

Answer (score -1):

It should be the ActivityContext. Besides your methods should take the format of..

```
void    onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)

void    onDisabled(Context context)

void    onEnabled(Context context)

void    onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)

void    onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
```

Where context should be

```
Context myContext
```

or anything of this nature.

Comment: There may not even *be* an `Activity`. Whatever the `Context` is, that would seem to be an unlikely candidate.